# How can I call a video from adapter in android tv and use functions like autoplay

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, android-tv

I want to call a video from adapter outside main activity and use functions like autoplay or full screen. I am working with Android tv

Actually i call the video from the adapter and the video is loaded but minimized. I need to clic on full screen and play on video controls to see the video like I need.

I am stuck with this. Any help is welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `PlaybackOverlayFragment`. I would highly recommend looking at the [androidtv-Leanback](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) example that the leanback team put together. Here is [the file](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/PlaybackOverlayFragment.java) that you may find particularly helpful.

There is a lot that goes into proper video playback but following this example as well as [this one](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase) should be very useful.

Let me know if you have a more targeted issue with video playback.

The autoplay is found at the top of the `PlaybackOverlayFragment` where they use a boolean which that call on anytime `onResume()` is called which tells the fragment if it should play or not.